# Designing Mac apps to be full screen

Tags: macos

I'm making a Mac app and want to enable the full screen function. I went to the widow's attributes inspector and changed the full screen to auxiliary. When I click the full screen button running the app it goes to full screen but the window stays the same size, but in full screen. 
Is there a way where I can make the app's content fill up the entire screen?

Comment: You don't want "auxiliary", you apparently want "primary".

Comment: I did auxiliary. I never selected primary.